# Azure Bastion terminal: copy/paste no working as excpected, how can i confgure it correctly?

Tags: azure, browser, terminal, azure-vm, azure-bastion

I have private VM which i can only connect to using Azure Bastion.

once i connect to it using Bastion, a termial opens in my browser, however i can not copy/paste correctly:

example:

1. if have a file having multilines, and those lines have NO break lines, so if i copy them and paste them in terminal, so **i will have a break lines**.
2. or, if i would like to paste : `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluxcd/flux2/main/install/flux.sh | sudo bash` i got the following content `curl -s 6`

Any help please ?